# Outlook event RSVP graph api issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Created an Event with Microsoft Graph:

```
{
  "subject": "TEST",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "test event respond"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-22T00:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-22T00:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
  },
  "location": { "displayName": "Leena AI" },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "sachin@live.com",
        "name": "Sachin Goel"
      },
      "type": "optional"
    }
  ],
  "isReminderOn": false,
  "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15
}
```

If I try to accept the event from `sachin@live.com` user it throws an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "485528b0-dbbe-42f5-80c0-5fc91477fc31",
      "date": "2019-04-30T07:11:58"
    }
  }
}
```

sample request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{eventId}/accept
{
  "comment" : "respond from api"
}
```

It results in `NotFoundError` but this works from UI. I have tried different solution (updating permission, primary calendar) but nothing works

Are there any constraints with this flow at the API level?

Comment: There shouldn't be any constraints. I see two possible issues that could return such error. 1. Id of Event is incorrect. 2. You are using Application account with /me endpoint.

Comment: Event Id is correct. But I am using /me endpoints for graph apis.

Endpoint that I'm using:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/<eventID>/accept `

Comment: Your request (according to error message) is almost 6months old. Do you have anything more recent? `"date": "2019-04-30T07:11:58"`

Comment: Recent error message:
` "error": "404 - {\"error\":{\"code\":\"ErrorItemNotFound\",\"message\":\"The specified object was not found in the store.\",\"innerError\":{\"request-id\":\"a8dad80c-92b5-4c86-bb4f-acbf2308a516\",\"date\":\"2019-10-22T12:52:16\"}}}"`

Comment: Thanks
It gets resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Event ID for the `Event` you created in your mailbox is *not* going to be the same as the Event ID in the `sachin@live.com` mailbox.

You need to find the message with the `sachin@live.com` mailbox and then accept *that* id.